# Is It Possible to Apply Laravel Policy to Both Routes and Custom Function?

Tags: laravel, policy

I have Location Policy and one api and one custom helper for both i want to use same policy,

Here is example :

### **1. Routes/API to read location record :**

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'policy:view,location'], function () {
        // Read location
        Route::post('/locations/{location_id}', [
            'uses'       => 'LocationApiController@read'
        ]);
  });
```

### **2. Custom Function/Helper to read location record**

> LocationHelper.php

```
/**
 * Class LocationHelper.
 */
class LocationHelper
{
    /** @var LocationRepositoryInterface */
    private $locationRepo;

    /**
     * ReminderHelper constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->locationRepo = App::make(LocationRepositoryInterface::class);
    }

    /**
     * @param int $locationId
     */
    public function readLocation($locationId)
    {
        $this->locationRepo->read($locationId);
    }
}
```

### Problem is :

While calling location read route/api policy will apply, and while calling read funtion from `LocationHelper.php` it will not apply

What i want is apply same policy for both.

Is there any way to do this ??

Answer (score 1):

You can call the policy manually, after retrieving the user. For example:

```
$allowed = Auth::user()->can('view', Location::firstOrFail($locationId));
```

Return a 403 if when the user is not allowed to view the resource, like this:

```
abort_unless($allowed, 403);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, But Any other unified solution ?

Comment: You could create some abstraction of your own and try to add this check in the LocationRepository, e.g. let it implement a custom PolicyInterface, but I really don't think it will make things much easier. Laravel does not offer authorization checks for custom helper methods out of the box.